# Building debian package fails when destination is /usr/local/bin

Tags: debian, packaging

I created a very simple C project and want to build a debian package from it.
Manually building the C project via the Makefile works as expected, it build the binary and can be installed in /usr/local/bin. When trying to build a debian packages however it fails with
`dh_usrlocal: error: debian/myhelloworld/usr/local/bin/myhelloworld is not a directory`

The Makefile looks like this:

```
prefix = /usr/local/bin

all: src/myhelloworld

src/hello: src/myhelloworld.c
    @echo "CFLAGS=$(CFLAGS)" | \
        fold -s -w 70 | \
        sed -e 's/^/# /'
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(LDCFLAGS) -o $@ $^

install: src/myhelloworld
    install -D src/myhelloworld \
        $(DESTDIR)$(prefix)/myhelloworld

clean:
    -rm -f src/myhelloworld

distclean: clean

uninstall:
    -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(prefix)/myhelloworld

.PHONY: all install clean distclean uninstall
```

The debian directory is created with `debmake` and i use `debuild` for building.

The project structure looks like:

```
.
├── debian
│   ├── changelog
│   ├── control
│   ├── copyright
│   ├── debhelper-build-stamp
│   ├── files
│   ├── myhelloworld
│   │   ├── DEBIAN
│   │   │   ├── control
│   │   │   └── md5sums
│   │   └── usr
│   │       ├── myhelloworld
│   │       └── share
│   │           └── doc
│   │               └── myhelloworld
│   │                   ├── changelog.Debian.gz
│   │                   ├── copyright
│   │                   └── README.Debian
│   ├── myhelloworld.debhelper.log
│   ├── myhelloworld.substvars
│   ├── patches
│   │   └── series
│   ├── README.Debian
│   ├── rules
│   ├── source
│   │   ├── format
│   │   └── local-options
│   └── watch
├── LICENSE
├── Makefile
└── src
    ├── myhelloworld
    └── myhelloworld.c
```

I have tried to change the default `debian/rules` file to override the dh_auto_install so it looks like:

```
%:
    dh $@  

override_dh_auto_install:
    dh_auto_install -- prefix=/usr/local/bin
```

This fails too.
I did check that the binary does exist in `debian/myhelloworld/usr/local/bin`.

I tried to change the prefix to just `/usr/bin`. This makes it possible to successfully build the package, but the containing binary is now installed in `/usr/bin`.

From the error message it seems like debuild expects the `myhelloworld` to be a directory, but this is the binary.
So why is debuild failing on my `/usr/local/bin` as destination.

Build log:

```
ep@ep-xps:~/sandbox/myhelloworld-1.0$ debuild 
 dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -ui
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source package myhelloworld
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source version 1.0-1
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source distribution UNRELEASED
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source changed by Erik <>
 dpkg-source --before-build .
dpkg-buildpackage: info: host architecture amd64
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
dh clean  
   dh_auto_clean
        make -j12 distclean
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ep/sandbox/myhelloworld-1.0'
rm -f src/myhelloworld
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ep/sandbox/myhelloworld-1.0'
   dh_clean
 dpkg-source -b .
dpkg-source: warning: no source format specified in debian/source/format, see dpkg-source(1)
dpkg-source: info: using source format '1.0'
dpkg-source: info: building myhelloworld using existing myhelloworld_1.0.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: building myhelloworld in myhelloworld_1.0-1.diff.gz
dpkg-source: warning: newly created empty file 'LICENSE' will not be represented in diff
dpkg-source: warning: the diff modifies the following upstream files: 
 Makefile
 src/myhelloworld.c
dpkg-source: info: use the '3.0 (quilt)' format to have separate and documented changes to upstream files, see dpkg-source(1)
dpkg-source: info: building myhelloworld in myhelloworld_1.0-1.dsc
 debian/rules build
dh build  
   dh_update_autotools_config
   dh_autoreconf
   dh_auto_configure
   dh_auto_build
        make -j12 "INSTALL=install --strip-program=true"
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ep/sandbox/myhelloworld-1.0'
cc -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/home/ep/sandbox/myhelloworld-1.0=. -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -Wl,-z,relro  src/myhelloworld.c   -o src/myhelloworld
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ep/sandbox/myhelloworld-1.0'
   dh_auto_test
   create-stamp debian/debhelper-build-stamp
 fakeroot debian/rules binary
dh binary  
   dh_testroot
   dh_prep
   debian/rules override_dh_auto_install
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ep/sandbox/myhelloworld-1.0'
dh_auto_install -- prefix=/usr/local/bin
        make -j12 install DESTDIR=/home/ep/sandbox/myhelloworld-1.0/debian/myhelloworld AM_UPDATE_INFO_DIR=no "INSTALL=install --strip-program=true" prefix=/usr/local/bin
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ep/sandbox/myhelloworld-1.0'
install -D src/myhelloworld \
        /home/ep/sandbox/myhelloworld-1.0/debian/myhelloworld/usr/local/bin/myhelloworld
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ep/sandbox/myhelloworld-1.0'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ep/sandbox/myhelloworld-1.0'
   dh_installdocs
   dh_installchangelogs
   dh_perl
   dh_usrlocal
dh_usrlocal: error: debian/myhelloworld/usr/local/bin/myhelloworld is not a directory
make: *** [debian/rules:9: binary] Error 25
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary subprocess returned exit status 2
debuild: fatal error at line 1182:
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -ui failed
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Packages aren’t allowed to ship files in `/usr/local`](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#site-specific-programs), only directories, and this is enforced by `dh_usrlocal`.

The best fix is to follow Debian conventions and install in `/usr`:

```
override_dh_auto_install:
        dh_auto_install -- prefix=/usr/bin
```

If you really want to install to `/usr/local/bin`, override `dh_usrlocal` instead:

```
override_dh_usrlocal:
```

Note that prefixes are generally understood as the “root” under which the various directories are placed, so you’d have

```
prefix = /usr/local

…

install: src/myhelloworld
        install -D src/myhelloworld \
            $(DESTDIR)$(prefix)/bin/myhelloworld
```

This is why your initial attempt installed `myhelloworld` in `/usr`: `dh_auto_install` sets `prefix` to `/usr`. If you change your `Makefile` to the above, you can drop the `dh_auto_install` override entirely.

(There’s a slight typo in your `Makefile`, it should be  `$(LDFLAGS)`, not `$(LDCFLAGS)`.)

You might find [the Debian upstream guide](https://wiki.debian.org/UpstreamGuide) useful.

Comment: Not exactly sure why i wanted the /usr/local/bin, but `override_dh_usrlocal:`does the trick in that case. Sticking to the guide lines using `/usr/bin` seems the best approach after all. Thank you very much for the explanation.

Comment: @Erik Debian policy is that `/usr/local` is the place for a system administrator to install extra software, without conflicting with Debian packages. That's why `/usr/local` should be kept free of Debian files.

Comment: If something is against policy, and you're not even sure why you're doing it to begin with, the best course of action is usually to then *not do that thing*.

Comment: @Shadur-don't-feed-the-AI with the caveat that policy defines the Debian distribution, so packages which aren’t intended for inclusion in the distribution don’t have to abide by it. However the distribution’s tools can default to policy-compliant behaviour, which is the case here, and it often is *easier* to follow policy as you say. (I’m not disagreeing with you, just clarifying that policy isn’t applicable to *all* packages.)

Comment: @stephenkitt Right. And at that point the maxim "Don't needlessly multiply complications" applies.